# Using grails service in domain class

Tags: grails

I want to use a service in my Grails application. However, it is always null. I am using Grails version 1.1. How can I solve this problem?

Sample code:

```
 class A{
      String name;
      def testService;
      static transients=['testService']
 }
```

Can I use a service inside a domain class?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That should work. Note that since you're using 'def' you don't need to add it to the transients list. Are you trying to access it from a static method? It's an instance field, so you can only access it from instances.

The typical use case for injecting a service into a domain class is for validation. A custom validator gets passed the domain class instance being validated, so you can access the service from that:

```
static constraints = {
   name validator: { value, obj ->
      if (obj.testService.someMethod(value)) {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi I am trying to access it from def onLoad ={} closure.

Comment: Looks like the dependency injection happens after the onLoad event, so you'll need to pull it from the application context instead. Add this import: "import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder as AH" and then in your onLoad you can reference the service as "def testService = AH.application.mainContext.testService"

Answer (score 11):

Short answer is. Yes you can use service inside domain class.

Here is an sample code where domain class gets access to the authenticate service from acegi plugin. It works without problems.

```
class Deal {
    def authenticateService

    def afterInsert() {
        def user = authenticateService.userDomain();
        ....
    }
....
}
```

Comment: This is actually the better answer! I had the whole thing backwards. I shouldn't have tried to access the db from the service, I should inject the service into the Domain class and run the code with the grails "triggers" like afterInsert, as you point out.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize Burt and Remis' answers:
In the domain custom validator, you have to use `obj.testService` rather than use `testService` directly. If you wanna use service in the domain custom validator:

```
static constraints = {
   name validator: { value, obj ->
      if (obj.testService.someMethod(value)) {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

But in other methods, including `afterInsert` and other private/public methods, use `testService` is fine.

```
 def someMethod() {
    def user = testService.serviceMethod();
    ....
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error in my `beforeUpdate()` when I save it from a different Domain's Service class. But when I save from its service class it works fine. `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method sendReservationUpdate() on null object`