# In Grails, how do I apply an inList constraint from a 3rd party data source?

Tags: grails

Let's say I have the following model:

```
class Product {
    String name
    String price
    String currency

    static constraints = {
        currency inList: ['USD', 'EUR']
}
```

Now we have a new requirement that `inList` constraint for `currency` must be pulled from a service:

```
class CurrencyService {
    def getAvailableCurrencies = {
        ...
    }
}
```

How do I make this work? I tried:

```
class Product {
    def currencyService
    ...

    static constraints = {
        currency inList: currencyService.getAvailableCurrencies()
    }
}
```

But I can't access the `currencyService` instance in the `static constraints` context. I also tried using `static currencyService`, but this likewise does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: This could provide some pointers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459897/using-grails-service-in-domain-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As dmahapatro mentioned above, you could use a [custom validator](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Constraints/validator.html) which uses your service:

```
static constraints = {
    currency validator: { value, obj ->
        if (!(value in obj.currencyService.getAvailableCurrencies())) 
            return ['invalid.currency']
    }
}
```