# How do I inject service-like components to Grails domain objects?

Tags: grails, dependency-injection, grails-domain-class

I've never used Grails services before, but according to my Web searches, they can be injected into domain objects. So, if I have the following domain class (assume that `BookService` is defined somewhere),

```
class Book {

    BookService bookService

}
```

when I instantiate a `Book` object using, `def book = new Book()`, `book.bookService` should be set?

If that's the case, what if I want to inject external services (or service-like components)? For example, if there's an ISBN API client available, can I expect grails to inject it the same way? For example, say the client is `IsbnApi`, how do I automatically inject like it's another service? Will the code below work?

```
class Book {

    @Transient
    @Autowire
    IsbnApi isbnApi

}
```

Based on the earlier responses to this question, I've already defined the domain class this way:

```
class Book {

    static transients = ['isbnApi']

    IsbnApi isbnApi

}
```

Now, this may be all that I need, but I also want to test that the automatic injection would work even *without having to run the app*. In my unit tests, I have to set the mock "service" manually.

```
IsbnApi isbnApi = Mock()
Book book = new Book()
book.isbnApi = mockIsbnApi
```

I attempted to check automatic injection by moving the test to `test/integration` and set the beans using `doWithSpring`.

```
def doWithSpring() {
    isbnApi = (InstanceFactoryBean, mockIsbnApi, isbnApi)
}

void "test automatic injection"() {
    given:
    IsbnApi isbnApi = Mock()
    Book book = new Book()
    //removed: book.isbnApi = mockIsbnApi

    expect:
    book.isbnApi //this fails
}
```

I also found additional information from [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2460029/404604). In particular,

> Note that *since you're using 'def' you don't need to add it to the
>   transients list*. Are you trying to access it from a static method?
>   It's an instance field, so you can only access it from instances.

Comment: Where is your IsbnApi stored? groovy/src?

Comment: It can be anywhere: `src/groovy`, or from another jar, etc.

Answer (score 3):

By convention Grails services are automatically candidates for dependency injection (= they can be injected into other classes). If you want to other classes you have to add them to `conf/spring/resources.groovy`.

E.g.:

```
import foo.bar.IsbnApi

beans = {
  isbnApi(IsbnApi)
}
```

Have a look at the [Bean Builder](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/spring.html) documentation section.

To make sure that your field is not treat as a persistent property, you can use the static `transients` field.

For example:

```
class User {
  def grailsApplication
  static transients = ['grailsApplication']
}
```

See [transients documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.3/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html)

Comment: Is this enough so that Grails does not mistake `def isbnApi` as a persistent property? If Grails finds it in `resources.groovy` does it automatically treat it as injected property instead of a persistent one? How can I verify this through unit tests?

Comment: You can use the `transients` field for this (updated the answer)

Comment: Is there a way to test this? `doWithSpring` doesn't seem to work when I call, for example, `Book book = new Book()`.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you want to test? I don't think `doWithSpring` is called in unit tests. Maybe it is called in integration tests. During unit tests you do not have a spring application context, so dependency injection does not work. You should have a look at the testind documentation: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html

Comment: I want to set a mock behavior to the service to test the domain class. I want to be able to automatically inject the mock service as it would be in the actually running application so I can verify everything works as expected.

Comment: As I said dependency injection does not work in unit tests. So you have to use `book.yourService = mockService;`. Or use integration tests.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did. However, just to test, I moved the test to `test/integration`, removed `book.youService = mockService`, declared beans in `doWithSpring()`, but I still got `NullPointerException`.

Comment: You should create a new question for this and post your code there. I think this has nothing to do with the original question you asked here.

Comment: @PsychoPunch add whatever you did to the description for your question. And also code.

Comment: @micha, Lalit Agarwal: I've updated the question to add details. I think that the follow up questions are related to to the original, since, in principle, we can only believe that something works if we can test it in some way.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the already accepted answers, as from grails 3.2.x you will need to enable autowiring on the domain ojbect in the mapping block or globally in the application config

```
class Book {

    static transients = ['isbnApi']

    IsbnApi isbnApi

    static mapping = {
        autowire true
    }
}
```

It is disabled by default to improve read performance so perhaps it's best to find alternative approach instead of enabling it.

http://grailsblog.objectcomputing.com/posts/2017/05/09/injecting-a-service-into-a-domain-class.html